# Power of a parameter which is starred

Tags: math-mode

How can I write star of a parameter in power of two? I wrote:

```
$x^*^2$
```

but it is not what I am searching for.

Comment: Do any of these give what you want? `${x^\ast}^2$`, `${x^2}^\ast$`, `$x^{2\ast}$`, `$x^{\ast 2}$`

Comment: Depending on your use, this notation might be confusing. I'd probably suggest `(x^*)^2`.

Answer (score 8):

Here are three possibilities; pick the one that best suits your typesetting needs.

[image]

I have a hunch that you'll want the second possibility; however, it's just a hunch.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$x^{*2} \quad {x^*}^2 \quad x^{*^2}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: As @Werner has noted in a comment, the output of `{x^*}^2` may leave some readers confused as to what exactly is being squared. Writing `(x^*)^2` should serve to remove any possible confusion.